# Wolfram Cloud app, iOS, ServiceConnect and Dropbox

Tags: wolfram-cloud, webservices

I'm trying to use some files on Dropbox, via `ServiceConnect[]` in the Wolfram Cloud app in iOS.

I can do this just fine on the Wolfram App on MacOS, and via Wolfram Cloud in Safari. However, when I try to do this via the iOS App I get a never ending 'spinner' (Tumbler, CA-based-busy indicator? What are we going to call that thing?)

[image: Service connect failure]

Basically, a `ServiceObject` is returned immediately, then the dialog box sits there until it is dismissed. The resulting `ServiceObject` is invalid and or useless.

Does anyone have any ideas here? Is this a 'bug'™?

Comment: I'm curious why the "TM"  on the "bug"?

Comment: I've forwarded this to our Cloud and Mobile teams to investigate.